# Debugging KML in GE client

Tags: debugging, kml, google-earth

Working with Google Earth 6.2.2.6613 client and KML files and I have a need for debugging .

I have situation where GE reports my KML file has made an "invalid HTTP request" and it displays the offending URL.

I can cut and paste the URL into a web browser and it returns the expected result.

So the question is " How can you get useful debugging information from the GE client?"

For example "invalid HTTP request" ? How ? whats invalid ? Does GE client run/have a debug log or mode ?

I am using Windows 7 Professional 64bit but I will need to test other versions ( Mac OS X ) in the future.

While a web proxy ( or my own globe server ) would allow me to see the http traffic , I need to see what happens in between requests in the GE client.

Answer (score 2):

Google Earth itself doesn't log what it does internally or have a debug mode to enable such logging. You can enable '*KML Error Handling*' in the Tools/Options/General menu which may give more information for invalid KML but validating the KML is best done with something like the [KML Validator](http://www.kmlvalidator.com/%E2%80%8E).

So the easiest way to debug Google Earth HTTP access is using a network analyzer such as the Fiddler Web Debugger to identify the network traffic.

Fiddler runs as an HTTP proxy and captures all web access showing the full HTTP request and response information. Just click '*Capture Traffic*' and then launch Google Earth to capture all HTTP traffic.

You can capture the HTTP session with hits to *kh.google.com, mw1.google.com, khmdb.google.com, mw2.google.com*, and so one with the full URL, HTTP headers for request and response, etc. There are many options for multiple views, filtering, decoding, timing information, and more. You'll see the selected Layers being downloaded as KMZ files.

```
Sample Web session

Result Port  Host            URL
200    HTTP  kh.google.com   /geauth?ct=free
200    HTTP      Tunnel to www.google.com:443
200    HTTP      Tunnel to accounts.google.com:443 
200    HTTP  kh.google.com   /flatfile?q2-0-q.534
200    HTTP  mw1.google.com  /mw-earth-vectordb/photos/360cities/360cities.kmz
200    HTTP  mw1.google.com  /mw-weather/base/files/kml/weather_en.kmz
...
```

After debugging you can stop Fiddler which restores the HTTP proxy settings back to normal.

I use this tool to quickly see what Google Earth is doing behind the scenes. It is easy to use and very friendly.

http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/

Comment: ok but fiddler won't tell you what the client is doing..only what traffic it sends/receives . You can get the same information if you run your own globe server.

Comment: If Google Earth client has a debug mode it's not documented nor is there any option in the client to enable debugging/logging. Neither is there any such option in the registry settings. Only debugging really is to examine the HTTP traffic.

Comment: Thanks Jason but HTTP traffic does not solve the problem. Consider the question asked "How do I know why link that GE reports as invalid is in invalid ?" HTTP traffic will only answer 1/2 ( at best ) of the possible reasons.